# ClearCase describe not working as expected

Tags: c++, linux, clearcase, clearcase-automation

I am trying to put version information for the release in one of the .cpp files using cleartool desc command.

These are some outputs for different desc commands:

```
cleartool desc -fmt "%[type]p\n" abc.cpp
Output:text_file

cleartool desc -fmt "%Nl" abc.cpp    // No output
cleartool desc -fmt "%[version]p\n" abc.cpp      //No Output
```

However, 
cleartool desc abc.cpp" does generate following output.

```
cleartool desc abc.cpp
Output: version "abc.cpp@@/main/DI_ABC_XYZ_1.0.0/1"
 created 2015-07-17T10:18:41+05:30 by ggne0118.engg@ggns1tthy01
 "Merge from XYZ 70471"
  Element Protection:
    User : UNIX:UID-999 : r-x
    Group: engg     : r-x
    Other:          : r-x
  element type: text_file
  predecessor version: /main/DI_ABC_XYZ_1.0.0/0
  Hyperlinks:
   Merge -> /data/project/common/XYZ/src/abc.cpp@@/main/1
    Merge <- /data/project/common/XYZ/src/abc.cpp@@/main/XYZ7047th
```

Why am i not getting any output for these two commands:
    cleartool desc -fmt "%Nl" abc.cpp    // No output
    cleartool desc -fmt "%[version]p\n" abc.cpp      //No Output

Comment: Can you explain why you think you should?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Is there some other version of desc that'll do this job? I just got introduced to ct desc for the first time and lack of information(or rather lack of clarity in the information) about desc command is making my job difficult which is to extract the version name. Actually, this is a legacy code, and cleartool desc -fmt "%Nl" abc.cpp has done the job so far just fine, but now it is not working as explained.

Answer (score 0):

When you consider [`fmt_ccase` man page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm?cp=SSSH27_7.1.1%2F9-0-0-6-6), you would see that:

- `%Nl` applies to versions: there might not be any label attached to that version.
  It displays "all attached labels; the null string otherwise": since there is no output, that means there is no attached label to the version currently selected by the view.
- `%[version]p` doesn't exist, `%n` or `%Vn` would exist.

`%[name]p` would the same as `%n`, which, for versions, is the same as `%[name]Xp` (extended version): `%[name]p` is always displayed as though `X` had been specified.

Comment: Can ypu please explain the %Nl option. When used what does it try to do exactly?

Comment: @user3814996 I have edited my answer to address your question.